# How can I reduce the height of combobox opening window in .net

Tags: asp.net, .net, wpf

How can I reduce the height of combobox opening window in .net

[image: How can I reduce the height of combobox opening window in .net]

Comment: in code i didn't use anything for the size,i just tried somthing in property window

Answer (score 1):

use [MaxDropDownHeight](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.maxdropdownheight(v=vs.110).aspx) of combo box like this :

```
<ComboBox MaxDropDownHeight="100"></ComboBox>
```

Provide whatever value you want in place of 100

Comment: can i use 50? because i don't want 100

Comment: Yes you can use whatever value you want as per your need

Comment: this is in asp.net right.,.how can i change in windows form application

Comment: You have used asp.net and WPF tags in your question. Is this Asp.Net or WPF ??